# Is there a way to remove a trailing '/' from a url in CloudWatch insights?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have a query that gets the total number of API requests with the same method, response code, path, etc. I do this by parsing certain aspects of the response body and one of them is the url but sometimes there is a trailing '/' at the end. Everything about the request is the same expect for that slash so it is creating duplicate rows. So I am wondering if there is a way to remove the trailing '/'? I have tried replace statements but haven't had any success, for example, | fields replace(url, '/$', '') as clean_url

The columns of the table: path, method, count, response code

[Screenshot of the table the query generates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUuRu.png)

Comment: Welcome! There's no '/' at the end in your screenshot, you mean at the start?

Comment: Thanks for responding @ErmiyaEskandary - The only difference between the requests is a trailing slash at the end for the url, for example, 'http:// localhost/test' and 'http:// localhost/test/' (i added space in url because it removed the '/' if its not there). In my query these are considered different requests and in turn is creating duplicate rows. The screenshot is showing that there are 2 separate rows for GET and PUT requests with 200 responses on the same path, when there should only be 1.

Comment: I was able to solve this by using the rtrim function. I parsed @messge and stored the url in a variable called 'url'. 
| fields rtrim(url, '/') as new_url